# customizing the tooltip for ggplotly when two dataframes are used in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tooltip, ggplotly

I have generated the following plot, which groups the data based on drug. I then created another data frame which summarized the main data by calculating the mean. These mean values(grouped by drug) are then added to the plot in triangular shapes. Using stat_summary connected the means. Now I would like to know how to add the tooltips for the means data (including x and y values with custom labels) to the plot using ggplotly. The current tooltip only includes the info for the main data

data:

```
Day,Drug,Sex,Y
1,A,Female,2.192306074
1,B,Male,4.551912798
1,B,Female,1.574070652
1,C,Female,-0.143946163
1,A,Male,5.144422967
1,C,Male,5.724705829
2,A,Male,2.691617258
2,B,Female,-3.0289955
2,C,Male,0.338102762
2,A,Female,-0.558581233
2,B,Female,-2.942620032
2,C,Male,1.024670497
3,A,Male,2.264980803
3,C,Female,2.103722883
3,A,Female,2.091621938
3,B,Male,1.535299922
3,B,Male,1.618399767
3,C,Female,0.136160703
```

After copying you may need to run the following command to convert it to the dataframe:

```
df <- read.delim("clipboard", sep = ",")
```

my variables are in string:

```
grouping_var <- "Drug"
x <- "Day"
y <- "Y"
color <- "Sex"
```

Here is the code for that the plot:

```
text <- paste("X:", df[[grouping_var]], "<br>",
              "Y:", df[[y]], "<br>",
              "group:", grouping_var, "<br>",
              "color:", color)
mean_df <- df %>% group_by(get(x), get(grouping_var)) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(get(y)), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  rename(x = 1, grouping_var = 2)

p <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = get(x), y = get(y), text = text)) +
  geom_point(aes_string(group = grouping_var, color = color)) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", aes_string(group = grouping_var), color = "red", lty = 2) +
  geom_point(data = mean_df, aes(x = x, y = Mean, group = grouping_var, color = grouping_var),
             pch = 2, size = 3,inherit.aes = F) + 

  xlab(x)+
  ylab(y)

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

The output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to achieve your desired result and add a tooltip to the summary points would be to map on the `text` aes in your second `geom_point` too. However, IMHO you could simplify your code a bit and as a side effect get rid of the `aes_string` (which was deprecated in `ggplot2 3.4.0` and should therefore be replaced by `aes`). To this end you could simply rename the original variables as `x`, `y`, `group` and `color`. Second, I use some small custom functions to create the tooltip texts. Finally, I replaced the `stat_summary` with a `geom_line`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

text1 <- function(x, y, group, color) {
  paste0(
    "X: ", x, "<br>",
    "Y: ", y, "<br>",
    "group (Drug): ", group, "<br>",
    "color (Sex): ", color
  )
}

text2 <- function(x, y, group, color) {
  paste0(
    "X: ", x, "<br>",
    "Y: ", y, "<br>",
    "group (Drug): ", group, "<br>"
  )
}

df <- df %>%
  rename(x = x, y = y, group = grouping_var, color = color) %>%
  mutate(text = text1(x, y, group, color))

mean_df <- df %>%
  group_by(x, group) %>%
  summarise(y = mean(y), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(text = text2(x, y, group, color))

p <- df %>% ggplot(aes(
  x = x, y = y, text = text
)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = group, color = color)) +
  geom_line(
    data = mean_df,
    aes(group = group),
    color = "red", lty = 2
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = mean_df,
    aes(color = group, text = text),
    pch = 2, size = 3
  ) +
  xlab(x) +
  ylab(y)

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way that the tooltip shows the grouping and colour variables name as well? for example something like this: X:1, Y:3.66, Group(Drug):A, color(Sex): Femal

Comment: Sure. Note: I have had another look and found a bug in my code. To fix that I switched back to your `mean_df` and replaced the stat_summary by a `geom_line` and `geom_point` and instead of using one function for the tooltip I use two.

Comment: here is my code but is not as efficient as yours in the following way by defining two texts. one for main data and one for the mean: text <- paste("X:", df$x, "<br>",
              "Y:", df$y, "<br>",
              "group:(", grouping_var,"):",df$group ,"<br>",
              "color:(", color,"):",df$color), and here is for the mean based on the mean_df dataframe text2 <- paste("X:", mean_df$x, "<br>",
               "Y:", mean_df$Mean, "<br>",
               "group:(", grouping_var,"):",mean_df$group ,"<br>",
               "color:(", color,"):",mean_df$group)

Comment: it seems to be a brilliant idea. but I don't want to hardcode the words' Drug or Sex. I think I can use your function and using paste in the same way I did in the comment above, bu not sure if it works well or I should add more arguments to your functions

Comment: Yeah. Basically it's not that important how you add the tooltip texts. And if your code works for you then it's the way to go.